# How to fix curl sslv3 alert handshake failure on Gentoo?

Tags: curl, ssl, https, handshake

I'm trying open a website with cURL like this:

```
$ curl -vH "Accept: application/json" https://www.rocketleaguereplays.com/api/replays/-1/
```

The output is:

```
*   Trying 104.24.114.83...
* Connected to www.rocketleaguereplays.com (104.24.114.83) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I have Linux kernel 4.4.0 and the newest cURL version installed:

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.47.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2f zlib/1.2.8 c-ares/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.6.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets
```

How can I fix this? On Ubuntu it works fine with cURL and same URL.

Comment: Now I fixed it. OpenSSL was compiled with the "bindist" USE-Flag. It works without this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, https://www.rocketleaguereplays.com uses outdated encryption (SSL3), you can force curl to connect to insecure sites like this using the -k (--insecure) switch.

Try this:
`curl -kvH "Accept: application/json" https://www.rocketleaguereplays.com/api/replays/-1/`

You could also try using the `-3` aka `--sslv3` switch, however, if curl was built without SSL3 support, then you need to compile your own version of curl, enabling SSL3.

EDIT: The op has found the problem.

I got confused by the error message.

This is a bug in gentoo:

https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=531540

Basically, when you build openssl with the bindist flag, the elyptic curve crypto is disabled. This site requires elyptic curve cryptography.

When I run this, I get the following:

`$ curl -vH "Accept: application/json" https://www.rocketleaguereplays.com/api/replays/-1/
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x6000572d0; line 1090 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 2400:cb00:2048:1::6818:7353...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x6000572d0; line 1143 (connection #0)
* Connected to www.rocketleaguereplays.com (2400:cb00:2048:1::6818:7353) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x6000572d0; line 1240 (connection #0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x6000572d0; line 1254 (connection #0)
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 <----
[...]`

So my curl uses elyptic curve with this site.

Comment: Thank you, but there is the same error :(

Comment: @Hanashi then why would you accept this answer

Comment: I think he accepted the answer after the [EDIT].